# Simple DocumentDb stored procedure

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create a simple DocumentDb stored procedure to better understand its concepts. In this example, I'm trying to return a all "Female" users. Do I need to concern myself with returning a single matching document or multiple documents?

Here's what my user object looks like:

```
{
   "id": "e85ee3d7-44a5-4250-a116-686e1c2a10f5"
   "firstName": "Jane",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "gender": "F"
}
```

And here's what my storedproc looks like so far:

```
function(gender) { 

   var context = getContext();
   var response = context.getResponse();
   var collection = context.getCollection();
   var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

   var filterQuery = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.gender = '" + gender + "'";
   // Now what???
}
```

I'd like to return ALL female users. There may be one or 10,000 female users.

I'd appreciate your help with this simple DocumentDb stored procedure. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track.

The next steps would be to run your filterQuery on the collection, and then place the query response in to the response variable.

For example:

```
function(gender) {
  var context = getContext();
  var response = context.getResponse();
  var collection = context.getCollection();
  var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

  var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.gender = "' + gender + '"';

  collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, filterQuery, {},
    function(err, documents) {
      response.setBody(response.getBody() + JSON.stringify(documents));
    }
  );
}
```

You can find some more samples and documentation on stored procedures on DocumentDB's website: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/

Comment: You want to be aware of continuation and evaluate the continuationToken -- your example might return a partial result set.
Here's the link to MSDN sample solution with Procedures & Triggers JS code: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-DocumentDB-NET-Code-6b3da8af

Comment: @Toons33, ditto on the thanks for MSDN sample. I have seen that sample page before but dismissed it because the title is "Azure DocumentDB .NET Code Samples" and I'm not writing in .NET. This time I finally noticed the "DocumentDB.Samples.ServerSideScripts" section, including the [Count.js](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-DocumentDB-NET-Code-6b3da8af/sourcecode?fileId=134860&pathId=1415025635) example that illustrates continuation nicely.

Comment: [Count.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/Count.js) can now be found in the Azure code samples library on GitHub. This sample code has moved several times, so in case the link goes bad, search GitHub for `org:Azure` and the terms `stored procedure continuationtoken`. One of these days maybe I (or someone else) will edit an example into the answer.