# Cosmos DB: Dynamic Input and Output in Stored Procedure

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, dynamic, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to stored procedure in Cosmos DB. But what I want is to do dynamic input and output in CosmosDB.

For example, we have a data model 'Student' where

```
{
        "FirstName": "Jack",
        "LastName": "Louis",
        "ZipCode": "12345"
    }
```

I want to be able to query any of these dynamically:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Student WHERE FirstName = "Jack"
SELECT FirstName, ZipCode FROM Student WHERE LastName= "Louis"
SELECT ZipCode FROM Student WHERE ZipCode = "12345"
```

I did some research and found out I still have to use SQL Query inside the stored procedure function.For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665767/simple-documentdb-stored-procedure):

```
function(gender) {
  var context = getContext();
  var response = context.getResponse();
  var collection = context.getCollection();
  var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

  var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.gender = "' + gender + '"';

  collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, filterQuery, {},
    function(err, documents) {
      response.setBody(response.getBody() + JSON.stringify(documents));
    }
  );
}
```

The filterQuery variable is the SQL Query and I cannot think of how to do dynamic input/output in this..

Any suggestions or thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could combine dynamic parameters into SQL queries to implement dynamic Input/output.

Please refer to my sample code:

```
function sample(column1,column2,filter,filterValue) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var query = 'SELECT c.' + column1 +',c.'+column2 + ' FROM c where c.' + filter + ' = '+ filterValue;
    console.log(query);

    var returnArray = [];
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        query,
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!feed || !feed.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody('no docs found');
            else {
                for(var i = 0;i<feed.length;i++){
                    var doc = feed[i];  
                    returnArray.push(doc);
                }
                getContext().getResponse().setBody(returnArray);
            }
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

result:

[image]

If the number of your arguments are indeterminate, I suggest you using `query column array` , `filter condition array` and `filter value array` then loop parse out their values to combine them into SQL.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Is this SQL injection free?

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions offered are sussepible to sql injection because of the string concatination